# Preserve changes to mouse sensitivity from xinput and xset after suspend

Tags: mouse, suspend

I am currently trying to get my mouse sensitivity to be preserved after my computer (running Ubuntu 15.10) wakes from suspend.
I am using the commands
`xset m 0 0` and
`xinput set-prop "Logitech Gaming Mouse G400" "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 1.25`
in order to get the sensitivity I desire. This is currently running from `~/.xsessionrc` (which works, I used to be running it on startup from the built-in Ubuntu utility, which also worked), but everything's reverting after my computer suspends.
I've got the script `99mouse_sensitivity.sh` in `/lib/systemd/system-sleep`:
`#! /bin/sh
if [ $1 = post ]; then
     xset m 0 0
     xinput set-prop "Logitech Gaming Mouse G400" "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 1.25
fi`
and have verified that it's running when it should (by adding `touch` commands in the script, which did work as intended), but it won't change my sensitivity. I'm assuming that this may be because the script runs before the X session starts, but I'm not sure if that's true/is the reason.
I'd appreciate any help getting this working!
Thanks,